# Calling Popen in Python on a MAC - Error can not find file

Tags: python, shell

When I try to shell out of my Python 3.51 program to run the Popen command I get the following errors.  Yet when I copy the exact string I'm passing to Popen to the Terminal command line it works fine and opens the file in Adobe Reader which is my default app for the .pdf files.

Here is the Code:

> ```
>   finalCall = r'open /Users/gbarnabic/Documents/1111/combined.pdf'
>     print(finalCall)
>     pid_id = subprocess.Popen(finalCall).pid
> ```

Here is the error:

> open /Users/gbarnabic/Documents/1111/combined.pdf
>   Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1549, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "pdfcomb2.py", line 212, in change_dir
>       self.openPDF(outFileName, pageNum)
>     File "pdfcomb2.py", line 426, in openPDF
>       subprocess.run(finalCall)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 696, in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'open /Users/gb/Documents/1111/combined.pdf'
>   Georges-MBP:filepicktest gb$ open /Users/gb/Documents/1111/combined.pdf
>   Georges-MBP:filepicktest gb$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Popen you need to set `shell=True` to pass command as a string or split command in a list of arguments. Could be done with `shlex`

```
import shlex
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('open ....'))
```

You could check example in documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

So the error here means that Python try to run file with name `open /Users/gb/Documents/1111/combined.pdf`. Obviously it doesn't exist

Comment: Damn it, I thought I read the docs on this but obviously missed that critical part.  Thanks!!